# Issue of Compatibility with Tablets on Google Play Can anyone please help me?

Tags: android, google-play

I am trying to publish an app and it is saying that it is not compatible with my Tablet. Below is the Manifest file for reference:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.abc.abc"
        android:versionCode="39"
        android:versionName="@string/version" >

        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="11"
            android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

        <supports-screens
            android:largeScreens="true"
            android:normalScreens="true"
            android:smallScreens="true"
            android:xlargeScreens="true" />

        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony"  android:required="false" />

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="com.ihi.atevent.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

     <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

        <application
            android:name=".MyApplication"
            android:allowBackup="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/icon"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:largeHeap="true"
            android:debuggable="false"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
                android:value="AIzaSyDVr8kzltrq2Q_8L9RywX1tyq_YSFwhTj0" />

           List of Activities, Services, Receivers and Broadcasters

       </application>

   </manifest>
```

Is there anything I need to change? Or is there something else which is causing problem?

Comment: It is compatible with some of the tablets so narrowing down the issue it is related to use of **CALL feature**. Can any one help me to tell how I can use the same code base for all type of devices. I cant remove this permission.

Answer (score 2):

It may be due to this permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

We had similar issue. The app was not visible in tablets after uploading on Play store. We had `CALL_PHONE` and `SEND_SMS` permissions added. After removing them, we uploded app again, and then it was compatible with tablets, too.

Comment: agree, some of the tablet don't have that function, to adhere norms they have this requirement

Comment: let me give it a try but I cant remove this permission. May I add <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" android:required="false"/> ???

Comment: android:required="false" is not for permission, I guess, Its for feature. Searching if I can find @AsifJutt

Comment: @AsifJutt probably, you can read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11210442/android-permission-call-phone-making-single-apk-for-phones-and-tablets) and internal links. That may be of use.

Comment: @FlamePrincessϡ The issue is no one has confirm answer for this. Do you have any experience related to this would be realyy helpful for me

Comment: @AsifJutt no. May be you can try removing permission and check if works in phone just with uses feature.

Answer (score 0):

Remove that support screen and try it once .

Comment: I added it after having the compatibility issue so I think it will not resolve this issue