# How to ask for android.permission.CALL_PHONE but still install on tablet?

Tags: android, google-play

I have an app I just published to the Play Store, that's showing up as "This app is incompatible with all of your devices" when I try to access it from tablets that lack telephony. It installs just fine on actual Android phones.

Here's the thing - we want users to be able to install the app on tablets and other devices that don't have phones, and to simply have the telephone functions not work. But if I include the CALL_PHONE permission in the manifest, the Play Store simply won't allow it to be installed.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

How do I get Google Play to allow an app that asks for the CALL_PHONE permission to install on a device that doesn't have a phone?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/11210568/603270. Worst case, having an alternate AndroidManifest with one line in it should be easy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can specify that Telephony is optional:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false"/>
```

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#permissions) says:

> The table below lists permissions that imply feature requirements
>   equivalent to those declared in  elements. Note that
>    declarations, including any declared android:required
>   attribute, **always take precedence** over features implied by the
>   permissions below.
>
> For any of the permissions below, you can disable filtering based on
>   the implied feature by explicitly declaring the implied feature
>   explicitly, in a  element, with an
>   android:required="false" attribute. For example, to disable any
>   filtering based on the CAMERA permission, you would add this
>    declaration to the manifest file:
>
> ```
> <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
> ```

In your case, the relevant portion of the table is:

```
Cateegory   This permission...     Implies This Feature Requirement 
Telephony   CALL_PHONE             android.hardware.telephony
            CALL_PRIVILEGED        android.hardware.telephony
            MODIFY_PHONE_STATE     android.hardware.telephony
            PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS android.hardware.telephony
            READ_SMS               android.hardware.telephony
            RECEIVE_SMS            android.hardware.telephony
            RECEIVE_MMS            android.hardware.telephony
            RECEIVE_WAP_PUSH       android.hardware.telephony
            SEND_SMS               android.hardware.telephony
            WRITE_APN_SETTINGS     android.hardware.telephony
            WRITE_SMS              android.hardware.telephony
```

Comment: Just in case it doesn't jump out at people - the solution is to add a <uses-feature/> element, not just to make the <uses-permission/> element. I'm just getting started with Android, and I'd not yet seen <uses-feature/>.